# Drawing Shape with ActionListener from Another Class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, paint

In my program, I am gonna ask for number of rectangles in JPanel and add them into the frame with create button. I want to call rectangles from another class. But I can not see my rectangles. When I write same paint method in my main class, I can see rectangles but they appers when I run the program. I want them to appear with actionlistener. What am I doing wrong? Here is my classes;

Rectangle Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Rectangle extends JFrame {

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public int getW() {
    return w;
}
public void setW(int w) {
    this.w = w;
}
public int getH() {
    return h;
}
public void setH(int h) {
    this.h = h;
}
public Color getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(Color c) {
    this.c = c;
}
private int x,y,w,h;
private Color c;
private asgn3 a3;
public Rectangle() {


}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
super.paint(g); 

g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getW(), getH());
g.setColor(Color.red);

}

}
```

My main JFrame class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JTextField recttext;
private JButton create;
private JLabel rectlabel,createlabel;
private int seat a;
private Rectangle[] rect;


public Example() {
    setLayout(null);

    recttext = new JTextField();
    recttext.setSize(150, 40);
    recttext.setLocation(100, 40);
    add(recttext);


    rectlabel = new JLabel("Rectangle number");
    rectlabel.setSize(100, 20);
    rectlabel.setLocation(102, 20);
    add(rectlabel);


    create = new JButton("Create");
    create.setSize(70,30);
    create.setLocation(670, 20);
    add(create);
    create.addActionListener(this);


    setSize(800,800);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Example();

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


   if(e.getSource().equals(create)) {
    a = Integer.parseInt(recttext.getText());

    rect = new Rectangle[a];
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
        rect[i]= new Rectangle();

    }   

    for(int i=1;i<=a/10;i++) {
    for(int j=i;j<11;j++) {
        rect[i-1].setX((getWidth()/(a/10))*i+20);
        rect[i-1].setY(100+j*50);
        rect[i-1].setW(100);
        rect[i-1].setH(50);

        repaint();

    }
    }

}

}
}
```

Comment: Why does your Rectangle extend JFrame?

Answer (score 0):

> When I write same paint method in my main class

What paint method? All your code does is create an Array of Rectangle objects. You have no code to do any painting.

The way painting works is that you override the paintComponent() of a JPanel. So you need to create a custom JPanel for your painting. Then you create an ArrayList of Rectangle objects. In the paintComponent() method you iterate through the ArrayList and paint each Rectangle.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for a simple example to get you started.

You can also check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It demonstrates how you can dynamically add Rectangle objects to be painted. The key it so use the addRectangle(...) method each time you want to display another Rectangle.